# ElasticSearch update API script - create array of structures

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am using Elasticsearch 6.5. I am writing a script for an update API in painless. I need to add structures to an array of structures. If this field does not exist in the document (I can detect that) I am creating a new array with the first element:

```
ctx._source.myStructArr = new def[] {struct_1};
```

Later I want to add additional structures:

```
ctx._source.myStructArr.add(struct_n);
```

but I receive the following error:

> "type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "dynamic method
>   [java.lang.Object[], add/1] not found"

How can I add an element to this array? Or maybe I should create/initialize an array in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ArrayList](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-types.html) instead of `new def[]`.

```
def arr = new ArrayList();
arr.add(struct_n)
```

Hope that helps.